# Why is my scoring system only coming up as 0?

Tags: python

I've used a scoring system that I thought was pretty fool proof but it always comes up as the score is 0

```
score = 0
answer1 = 1
if answer1 == 1:
  score + 2
else:
  pass
print(score)
```

Comment: Use `score += 2` to add the value. Also please never post code as images, simply copy/paste your code into your question and format it as code.

Comment: you cannot save your score +2 anywhere. if you want to save then score=score+2 or you can print(score+2)

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
if answer1 == 1:
  score + 2
```

Does not *modify* `score`. The expression `score + 2` creates a new value, and then *does nothing* with it.

You're off by one character. The `+=` operator will add to `score` and assign the result back into `score`.

```
score = 0
answer1 = 1

if answer1 == 1:
  score += 2

print(score)
```